# NoClassDefFoundError in MultipartEntityBuilder while uploading file

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, contenttype

I want to upload image and send data to server. I am using MultipartEntityBuilder for this. I am coding on Android Studio.

here is my code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(config.api_url+"profile.php");

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

if(mLastTakenImageAsJPEGFile!=null) {
    builder.addBinaryBody("image", mLastTakenImageAsJPEGFile);
}

builder.addTextBody("token", _appPrefs.getToken());
final HttpEntity reqEntity = builder.build();

httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

I am getting Runtime Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType 
at 
org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:146)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Take a Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941708/upload-file-by-http-post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284542/upload-photo-using-httppost-multipartentitybuilder

Answer (score 5):

I found this problem with httpmime 4.3.6, and i haven't found a solution, I suggest you use httpmime 4.2.1, it works fine.

```
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(file);
multipartEntity.addPart("image", new FileBody(file));
httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

you need to add `httpcore-4.2.3.jar` and `httpmime-4.3.2.jar` and if you using IOutils, use ByteStreams `guava-18.jar` don´t forget **internet permission** and **add .jar to your \projectName\app\libs folder** and sync as well.

Use this:

```
byte[] data;
data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

Instead of:

```
byte[] data;
data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```