# Java .wav get binary data

Tags: java, speech-recognition, wav, voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the Microsoft Project Oxford Speaker Recognition API REST, in order to create an enrollment I need to send a Binary Data of a .wav file. I already have the class that records and saves the .wav file, now I have to POST it, I just dunno how do I kinda "decode" the .wav file I have to that Binary Data that I want...

Appreciate any help.

Here's the link to what I'm trying to do: [Speaker Recognition Create Enrollment](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c).

Comment: I've used Apache's HTTPComponent/Client API in the past, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941708/upload-file-by-http-post/20941769#20941769)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java . Just store the bytes in whatever format you want instead of writing them to a dataline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll continue trying based on your answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation of the API](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c), it is mentioned that the "body" of the request is the raw binary data for the *.wav file that you have recorded. This means you just need to send the file as is without any decoding.